# Hibernate select query returns nothing

Tags: java, hibernate

I got a little issue with hibernate since hibernate doesn't accept a normal sql query syntax. When i send my query with a select statement which should return an exact integer of 37 to the database i get nothing in return instead. This is the query in sql syntax:
"select id from tbl_employee where bsn = '36372837'" this returns 37. But when i execute this query from within hibernate with al the object references and crap it doesn't work.

Please check my code and see if you know how to solve the problem:

```
public void RegisterWorkHours(TimeRegistration object)
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("timereg");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try
        {


            String get_employee_id = "SELECT emp.id FROM Employee as emp WHERE emp.bsn=:bsn";
            Query employee_query = em.createQuery(get_employee_id);
            employee_query.setParameter("bsn", object.getEmployee().getBsn());
            int id = employee_query.getFirstResult();
            System.out.println("query returns employee id: " + id);
            object.getEmployee().setId(id);


            String get_project_id = "SELECT p.projectID FROM Project as p WHERE p.projectname=:projectname";
            Query project_query = em.createQuery(get_project_id); 
            project_query.setParameter("projectname", object.getProject().getProjectname());
            int projectid = project_query.getFirstResult();
            System.out.println("query returns projectid: " + projectid);
            object.getProject().setProjectID(projectid);

            em.getTransaction().begin();



                em.persist(object);
                em.getTransaction().commit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Employee class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_employee")
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="employeeSequence", sequenceName="SEQ_EMPLOYEE", allocationSize =1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="employeeSequence")
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "bsn")
    @NaturalId
    private String bsn;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private String birthDate;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="house_number")
    private String houseNumber;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="zip")
    private String zip;

    //Constructor
    protected Employee() {}

    public Employee(String bsn, String firstname, String lastname)
    {
        setBsn(bsn);
        setFirstname(firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);

    }
    public Employee(String bsn, String firstname, String lastname, String address, String housenumber)
    {
        setBsn(bsn);
        setFirstname(firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);
        setAddress(address);
        setHouseNumber(housenumber);
    }
    public Employee(String bsn, String firstname, String lastname, String address, String housenumber, String zip, String city)
    {
        setBsn(bsn);
        setFirstname(firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);
        setAddress(address);
        setHouseNumber(housenumber);
        setZip(zip);
        setCity(city);
    }

    //The rest is one big list of getters and setters.
}
```

TimeRegistration class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_timeregtest")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class TimeRegistration
{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Employee employee;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="timeregSequence", sequenceName="SEQ_TIMEREG", allocationSize =1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="timeregSequence")
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name="date")
    private String date;


    @Column(name="hours")
    private int hours;

    //Constructor
    protected TimeRegistration() {}

    public TimeRegistration(Project project, Employee employee, String date, int hours  )
    {
        setProject(project);
        setEmployee(employee);
        setDate(date);
        setHours(hours);
    }

//the rest is all getter setter stuff
}
```

main void

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        Persistence persistence = new Persistence();
        Project project = new Project("AlphaMouse", "11-2-2013", "12-4-2019");
        Employee employee = new Employee("398723912", "Stoel",  "Stra");    
        TimeRegistration register = new TimeRegistration(project, employee, "21-2-2024", 8);
        persistence.RegisterWorkHours(register) ;
}}
```

Thanks in advance,
Benjamin

Comment: Probably going to need to see your Employee object and the mapping you have setup (or Annotations)

Comment: oke Kevin Crowell i added the Employee and TimeRegistration classes, i also added the main void with the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the method `getFirstResult()`. 
But this method returns the position (integer) of the record in the table.

To retrieve the record (object), you should use `getSingleResult()` instead.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html.

Answer (score 0):

Am not a JPA person so apologise if didnt make sense, try wrapping your query inside a transaction

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    String get_employee_id = "SELECT emp.id FROM Employee as emp WHERE emp.bsn=:bsn";
    Query employee_query = em.createQuery(get_employee_id);
    employee_query.setParameter("bsn", object.getEmployee().getBsn());
    long id = employee_query.getFirstResult();
    System.out.println("query returns employee id: " + id);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajan for your feedback it could have made sense but it did not work :(...

I hope some other people can help me.

Comment: @B Westra Try adding space between your equals and ":" in your query. "SELECT emp.id FROM Employee as emp WHERE emp.bsn = :bsn";

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.. it still returns 0 while it should return 37.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

```
    Integer id = (Integer) em.createQuery("select id from Employee where bsn =:bsn")
.setParameter("bsn", object.getEmployee.getBsn())
.getSingleResult();
```

getSingleResult() returns an object, so that is why you have to use Integer instead of int.